# Trying to use DeepCopy function available with Rally SDK 2.0rc3 to copy MMF/Feature getting error object is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally, appsdk2

Trying to use DeepCopy feature available with Rally SDK 2.0rc3 to copy MMF/Feature getting error Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

I am new to Rally, I think I am doing something wrong while calling the DeepCopy function, any suggestions on this. Thanks in advance

This is the code where I am calling DeepCopy function

```
Ext.create('Rally.ui.dialog.ChooserDialog', {
    //model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
    //fetch: ['FormattedID','Name','UserStories'],
    width: 450,
    autoScroll: true,
    height: 525,
    title: 'Select to Copy',
    pageSize: 100,
    autoLoad: true,                 
    artifactTypes: ['portfolioitem'],
    autoShow: true,
    listeners: {
        //load: this._onDataLoaded,
        artifactChosen: function(selectedRecord) {
            console.log("copied element", Rally.util.DeepCopy(selectedRecord));
        },
        scope: this
    },
    storeConfig : {
        filters: [
            {
                property: 'PortfolioItemType.Name',
                operator: '=',
                value: 'Feature'
            }
        ]
    }
}),
```

Comment: what is selectedRecord? e.g. `console.log("copied element", selectedRecord, Rally.util.DeepCopy(selectedRecord));`?

Comment: @pherris- Thanks for the reply. selectedRecord is the feature object. do u have any example of deepcopy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close - try calling the copy method on the Rally.util.DeepCopy singleton:

```
Rally.util.DeepCopy.copy(selectedRecord);
```

In case you didn't have the API link:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/api/Rally.util.DeepCopy

Comment: I tried this too. But it shows me error saying "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". do u have any idea about this

Comment: This means your object likely has circular references in it which makes it impossible to traverse. Can you examine selectedRecord and copy only part of it? If you show us that object maybe we can figure it out.

Comment: selectedRecord feature object some part is 'hasListeners: n__proto__: n__proto__: n__proto__: n__proto__: c__proto__: Object_decr_: function (h){if(!--this[h]){delete this[h]}}_incr_: function (h){if(this.hasOwnProperty(h)){++this[h]}else{this[h]=1}}__proto__: Objectid: "Rally.domain.v2.0.project.6674950537.PortfolioItem-9470040518"index: 1internalId: "x-gen1079"'

Comment: I am guessing the record has a reference to its store which has a reference back to its records.  Why do you need to copy the record?  You can always create a new record from its raw data if you still need to do this...

Comment: @KyleMorse thanks kyle, but I am not able to find that loop abt which u r talking about..I want to copy feature, MMF thats why. Yes I can create new record too..I tried that one too..but FormattedID is not getting generated for new record.   see the below question by me (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845532/formattedid-is-not-getting-generated-for-new-feature-record)

Comment: For the record the deep copy utility is only for client side copying.  You'll need to actually create and save a new record for it to be persisted in Rally: http://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/#!/guide/data_models